# How to use angular-google-maps <markers> directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using angular-google-maps in [my project](http://angular-google-maps.org/).

I'm trying to add multiple markers, using objects of the following definition:

```
vehicles = [
{
    stuff: "stuff",
    last_known_location: {
        latitude: number,
        longitude: number
    }
    
},
{
    stuff: "stuff",
    last_known_location: {
        latitude: number,
        longitude: number
    }
    
},//...etc
]
```

My directive looks like:

```
<markers models='vehicles'
         coords='vehicles.last_known_location' >
</markers>
```

Vehicles is an array of objects as described above.

This doesn't work. If I change my model to just have properties of latitude and longitude and completely lose the `last_known_location` property and change my directive `coords='self'` then it works fine. What do I need to do to get this working with my json structure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you figured out, it's stated in here: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers that the value of the property *coords* must be between quotes.

**Also, in v1.1**, for each marker **you need to define an id** (the name of the id property is given by *idKey*), which defaults to model.id,

so, in your case, and for it to work now it would have to be

```
<markers models="vehicles" coords="'last_known_location'"></markers>
```

and the vehicles array, for instance:

```
$scope.vehicles = [{
  id: "first",
  stuff: "stuff",
  last_known_location: {
      latitude: 37.3694868,
      longitude: -5.9803275
  }
}];
```

(Notice the *id* property)

Comment: awesome , this helped me , their docs weren't 100% clear , I will probably go contribute to this github its helped me out a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to define the array again after you already defined it for you models.  Can you try:

```
<markers models='vehicles' coords='last_known_location'>  </markers>
```

If you didn't have them within last_known_location and just within the parent object, the API says you can use 'self' to identify the the objects contain lat and lng

Comment: Didn't work by removing vehicles from coords. It does work by putting lat and lon in the parent object, I don't want to do that.

Comment: What about using coords='self.last_known_location'

Comment: K, I'm stumped.  The only other way is to debug by going into the directives file and console.logging what is going on.  Sorry couldn't help more

Comment: Your markers syntax ended up being correct, but the problem was that the property "last_known_location" actually needed to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Interesting, wonder if the underscores in the key somehow interfered with how AngularJS parses things...  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, add `[]` to your definition of `last_known_location` in order to make it an array of objects. In this test page for Angular Google Maps, the coords do not work without it. http://www.directiv.es/angular-google-maps

Second, make sure `vehicles` is accessible to your module. The best way to do that is by making it a part of `$scope`.

```
angular.extend($scope, 
{
    vehicles:
        stuff = "stuff",
        last_known_location:  [{
          latitude: 45,
          longitude: -74
        }]
  });
```

Then the markup in @jOshT's response will work:

```
<marker models='vehicles' coords='last_known_location'>  </markers>
```

**UPDATE**

Per comments, I misunderstood that this implementation is using [markers](http://angular-google-maps.org/api#markers) instead of [marker](http://angular-google-maps.org/api#marker). The former requires the `coords` object to be a `string` and the later requires an  `expression`. Serializing the `last_known_location` with the original code will work.

Comment: Also, vehicles is visible in the controller, I am able to get this to work if I ditch the last_known_location property.

Comment: Look more closely at the object definition in my answer please. `last_known_location` needs to be an array with object inside.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect for what I am trying to do. The code sample at that link is NOT what I am trying to do. From the docs: "coords:The name of the property containing the marker coordinates. Must point to an object having latitude and longitude properties." I am trying to use the markers directive http://angular-google-maps.org/api#markers

Comment: That page also states that unlike in the `marker` element, for `markers` the `coords` is a string, not an expression. Try serializing your `last_known_location`

Comment: This comment is correct, I had actually just tried that right before you made this comment.

Comment: No, it is working now, but using my original code and serializing last_known_location